# Howto prepare QTCreator for linux driver & kernel development

Tags: linux, qt-creator

i tried a few IDEs on linux to develop driver in C. QtCreator suits best for me.
I need the IDE just for the intellisence (codecompletion, jump to functions on click.. etc.) for quicker coding.

Has anyone configured QTCreator for such needs.
E.g. what do i have to do to get intellisence for a struct?

regards
camelord.

Answer (score 8):

A better solution is to import the linux source with "Import Existing Project".
Add all the files your ARCH requires.
Once created edit the .includes file and remove all the include dirs listed.

Then just add the few that linux uses.

```
include
arch/<ARCH>/include
arch/<ARCH>/mach-<MACH>/include
arch/<ARCH>/<PLATFORM>/include
```

Now edit .config, this is the best bit.
Add something like the following.

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define __arm__
#define __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ 7

#include <linux/kconfig.h>
```

It's the #include that brings in all of the autoconf stuff you mostly want.

Do a make V=1 to see the standard defines that the Kernel build uses.

Also if you're using a cross compiler, set up as usual in "Build & Run" Compilers tab.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem.
I found a solution, how to prepare Qt Creator to the linux Kernel development in the Ubuntu.

**Prepare include paths:**

1. Create Non-Qt project (Plan C-Project).
2. Add your files to project.
3. Download your linux-headers. On Ubuntu 14.04 `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
4. Configuring your *.pro file:

   ```
   TEMPLATE = app
   CONFIG += console
   CONFIG -= app_bundle
   CONFIG -= qt

   ARCH=arm64
   SRC_PROJECT_PATH = /home/user/my_LKM_project
   LINUX_HEADERS_PATH = /usr/src/linux-headers-$$system(uname -r)

   SOURCES += $$system(find -L $$SRC_PROJECT_PATH -type f -name "*.c" -o -name "*.S" )
   HEADERS += $$system(find -L $$SRC_PROJECT_PATH -type f -name "*.h" )
   OTHER_FILES += $$system(find -L $$SRC_PROJECT_PATH -type f -not -name "*.h" -not -name "*.c" -not -name "*.S" )

   INCLUDEPATH += $$system(find -L $$SRC_PROJECT_PATH -type d)
   INCLUDEPATH += $$system(find -L $$LINUX_HEADERS_PATH/include -type d)
   INCLUDEPATH += $$system(find -L $$LINUX_HEADERS_PATH/arch/$$ARCH/include -type d)
   ```

**Building:**

1. Create Makefile
2. In the Qt Creator go to the "Projects" and unset the "Shadow build"
3. In the "Build Steps" remove all items and add "make" item. In the make item in the first field set make, in the second field set command for your Makefile.
   Also you can set your build script.

Answer (score 3):

I found answer [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13147). To acomplish this you need to add

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-3.1.8-1-ARCH/include
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -I/usr/src/linux-3.1.8-1-ARCH/include
```

to all .pro files that are used for building kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment, so I'll add a comment here to RedEyed's answer. I had to escape the quotes, otherwise I got an error message from the find command:

```
SOURCES += $$system(find -L $$SRC_PROJECT_PATH -type f -name \"*.c\" -o -name \"*.S\" )
```

Comment: You could propose this as an [edit to their question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28188965/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to:

1. build linux kernel as usual, but with verbose output: `make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 | tee build.log`
2. Use `prepare_kernel_project.py` from [this repo](https://github.com/TheMeaningfulEngineer/linux-in-qtcreator) (the script takes `build.log` and parses files/options used for building in the previous step, and then creates QtCreator project):

```
~/linux$ git clone https://github.com/TheMeaningfulEngineer/linux-in-qtcreator.git
~/linux$ cp linux-in-qtcreator/prepare_kernel_project.py .
~/linux$ chmod 755 prepare_kernel_project.py
~/linux$ ./prepare_kernel_project.py build.log linux
```

3. And finally, open the project in QtCreator: `File -> Open File or Project -> linux/linux.creator`

P.S. [Source](https://meaningfulengineer.com/Kernel-developemnt-in-QtCreator/)