# What IDE should I use for Linux module development?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and am looking to start developing Linux modules. I use Visual Studio for C development in Windows, but I guess that's not an option for Linux. What would be a good IDE to work Linux modules ?

Comment: An older but similar question: [what-ide-would-be-good-for-linux-kernel-driver-development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149321/what-ide-would-be-good-for-linux-kernel-driver-development)

Comment: I think that the best way for this is *QtCreator*.
See how to configure it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28188965/3049753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do there are number to choose from. However I think the closest one to  visual studio equivalent will be [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org).

From the FAQ:

> Eclipse is an open source community whose projects are focused on
> building an extensible development platform, runtimes and application
> frameworks for building, deploying and managing software across the
> entire software lifecycle. Many people know us, and hopefully love us,
> as a Java IDE but Eclipse is much more than a Java IDE.
>
> The Eclipse open source community has over 200 open source projects.
> These projects can be conceptually organized into seven different
> "pillars" or categories:

- Enterprise Development
- Embedded and Device Development
- Rich Client Platform
- Rich Internet Applications
- Application Frameworks
- Application Lifecycle Management (ALM)
- Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)

> The Eclipse community is also supported by a large and vibrant ecosystem of major IT > > > solution providers, innovative start-ups, universities and research institutions and > individuals that extend, support and complement the Eclipse Platform.
>
> One very exciting thing about Eclipse is that many people are using
> Eclipse in ways that we have never imagined. The common thread is that
> they are building innovative, industrial-strength software and want to
> use great tools, frameworks and runtimes to make their job easier.

Answer (score 2):

It is all just a matter of personal preference.

Apart from what was mentioned in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149321/what-ide-would-be-good-for-linux-kernel-driver-development), I would like to name two more.

In our kernel-related projects, my colleagues and I currently use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) lightweight IDE which is more than enough for us.

I also use [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) that resembles Visual Studio 2003 very much, it also does its job well. It has more advanced code completion features than Geany, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Eclispe is always a popular choice and a very nice IDE

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (http://eclipse.org/) is a pretty good IDE. I have tried a few other ones such as KDevelop etc, but I have always found Eclipse to be the best and most stable.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse + CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) + at least a dual core processor and some Go of RAM and it will be a great adventure to navigate into the kernel sources.