# How to navigate C source code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ctags, cscope

I was writing much java code lately and got quite used to IDE features like jumping to definitions.

Now I'm working on C (reading some kernel code) and wonder if there is any similar tooling for that language, too.

I am aware of `ctags`, `cscope`, and lxr, but they seem to rely much on pattern matching and do not really understand the code.

For example I have some code using `struct file`, how do I navigate to the definition of that struct in order to determine the available fields?

Even if I know that it is defined in `fs.h` and it contains a field of type `fmode_t` defined in `types.h` as `unsigned __bitwise__`, is there a way to get the semantics of the single bits? (Probably by finding the `FMODE_*` constants in `fs.h` again.)

Is this kind of (eclipse-like) direct navigating possible, or do I really have to do much guessing if I do not know all of this before?

Comment: I use OpenGrok for this: http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/ It is web interface on `ctags` which is extremely useful. But it fails to find `struct file` definition because `struct file* file` constructs are too popular in kernel. But it works well with typedefs: http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=defs%3Afmode_t&path=%2Flinux%2Fstable%2F&project=linux

Comment: > Is this kind of (eclipse-like) direct navigating possible < Didn't you try that with Eclipse CDT? AFAIK, it supports that.

Comment: Parsing C code correctly (which is required for navigating it) is a hard problem. All the #defines, #ifdefs, typedefs, different builds configured outside source code, and so on and so on, basically mean that to have 100% correct source code navigation, the code needs to be fully parsed as if by compiler. Some IDEs do a decent job (I use Qt Creator, but I'm sure there are better IDEs for C projects). Good "Find in files" is your friend here, and knowing how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you like eclipse try [nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html). It's for cuda, but I think it gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try QtCreator for the Linux kernel. I wrote how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417732/howto-prepare-qtcreator-for-linux-driver-kernel-development/28188965#28188965).
It is the best IDE for Linux kernel development I have ever seen.